# adding a link to a picture html

Tags: html, hyperlink

I've added a page link to a picture for my website, but it does not load the website because the link goes the directory therefore the webpages do not appear. My code is below:

```
<a href="www.w3schools.com">
<img src="Images/insta.png" alt="" style="width:7%; height:7%;">
</a>
```

When I click on the image it says file not found.

Comment: You need an absolute URL. The entire URL of the image.

Comment: i must have the image stored in a folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're linking to a page on an external site, you will need to provide the entire URL of the page in question, which includes the protocol. In this instance, that would be `http://www.w3schools.com/`.

By linking to `www.w3schools.com`, you are telling the browser to load that URL relative to the page you're linking from so, if this link were on a page located at `http://domain.tld/page.html`, clicking on it would attempt to load `http://domain.tld/www.w3schools.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `http://` OR `https://` for your website link:

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/">
  <img src="Images/insta.png" alt="" style="width:7%; height:7%;">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">
    <img src="Images/insta.png" alt="" style="width:7%; height:7%;">
</a>
```

Without the http:// your link will be something like: youraddress/www.w3schools.com

And pay attention if you image is in the correct folder called Images